# Excluding Certain Files in Azure CI Pipeline (YAML)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a CI pipeline (YAML) that builds a repo that will deploy into an existing Azure Function. The CI pipeline is doing it is job. However, after it is done, and I go to Function App -> App files -> I can see the azure-pipeline.yml is included in there (or i think it was included in the build process). I have tried using paths and exclude but they dont work. My question is, how do I exclude only that azure-pipeline.yml so that after the pipeline is done building, the azure-pipeline.yml is not in App files in Function App. Below is my YAML

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    exclude:
      - README.md
      - azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'DevOps-Test'
  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'test'
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'vs2017-win2016'
  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

  
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        if (Test-Path "extensions.csproj") {
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./$(workingDirectory)/bin
        }
      displayName: 'Build extensions'
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: $(workingDirectory)
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true
    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
      displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: functionApp
        appName: $(functionAppName)
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

Answer (score 7):

The following syntax means file `README.md` or `azure-pipelines.yml` won't trigger the build. It doesn't mean file `README.md` or `azure-pipelines.yml` are excluded in the working directory.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    exclude:
      - README.md
      - azure-pipelines.yml
```

I've noticed you tried archiving folder `$(workingDirectory)`, and `workingDirectory` defined in variable which was actually `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/`. `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded.

Obviously, file `README.md` and `azure-pipelines.yml` are in the source code, so they are archived too. You could add a `CopyFiles task` before `ArchiveFiles task` to copy files you need from a source folder to a target folder using match patterns, then archive the target folder. For example:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) '
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(workingDirectory)'
    Contents: |
     **/*
     !*.md
     !*.yml
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) '

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files '
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) '
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here

```yaml
    - powershell: |
        if (Test-Path "extensions.csproj") {
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./$(workingDirectory)/bin
        }
      displayName: 'Build extensions'
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: $(workingDirectory)
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true
```

You produce your ouptut here `./$(workingDirectory)/bin` but you zipped `rootFolderOrFile: $(workingDirectory)`. Please change it to `rootFolderOrFile: $(workingDirectory)/bin`.

EDIT

Please add this before calling archive

```yaml
- script: |
    rm README.md
    rm azure-pipelines.yml
  workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
```

So you will remove them from folder which you later archive.

Comment: Please check how your working directory looks like by adding `- script: ls '$(workingDirectory)'` before `Archove files` step.

Comment: Here is my working directory, I want to exclude README.md and azure-pipelines.yml from being shown in App files in the Function App  https://imgur.com/a/tIT1wFw

Comment: This is a bit strange, but check my edit.